# /usr/bin/jsvc: No such file or directory Error when trying to run jsvc

Tags: java, jsvc

I got `/usr/bin/jsvc: No such file or directory` error when trying to run jsvc with my java program. I tried this

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
path/to/java/home
which java
/usr/bin/java
```

to check if I have java installed in the correct location and I still get errors. Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong? This is part of the command I am trying to run: `JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME /usr/bin/jsvc -cp /opt...`

Comment: Have you installed `jsvc`?  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html

Comment: I downloaded jsvc and the command still doesn't work